# Cannot delete Javascript object and make fresh instance in angular js scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem with creating fresh copy of JavaScript object and assigned to `$scope`. This object is bind to frontend form, so I must reset the data of this object. Here is the code:
This is JavaScript class:

```
var userInfo = (function () {
  function userInfo() {}

  var _refCode = "";
  var _country = {};
  var _language = {};
  var _userType = 0;
  var _retailer = {};

  userInfo.prototype.data = {
    refCode: function (value) {
      return angular.isDefined(value)
        ? (_refCode = value)
        : _refCode;
    },
    country: function (value) {
      return angular.isDefined(value)
        ? (_country = value)
        : _country;
    },
    language: function (value) {
      return angular.isDefined(value)
        ? (_language = value)
        : _language;
    },
    userType: function (value) {
      return angular.isDefined(value)
        ? (_userType = value)
        : _userType;
    },
    retailer: function (value) {
      return angular.isDefined(value)
        ? (_retailer = value)
        : _retailer;
    }
  }

  return userInfo;
})();
```

this is my angular controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
  $scope.initUserInfo = function () {

    //here make instance of the class
    var user_info = new userInfo();

    delete $scope.userInfo;
    $scope.userInfo = user_info;
  };

  $scope.initUserInfo();
});
```

But when I call the function `initUserInfo()` nothing happens. The data in `$scope.userInfo` is still there. What have I done wrong and how to delete information from `userInfo`?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks, I make changes and now my code look like, but when I

> console.log

I have following error:

> **Cannot read property 'data' of undefined - on the first console.log**
>
> **print old value - on second console.log**
>
> **print old value - on third console.log**

Аfter the execution of this function that was before her performance remains not erased.

```
   $scope.initUserInfo = function () {
    delete $scope.userInfo;
    var user_info = null;
    console.log("after delete: " + $scope.userInfo.data.refCode());//first console log
    user_info = new userInfo();
    $scope.userInfo = user_info;
    console.log("after assing: " + $scope.userInfo.data.refCode());
    $scope.userInfo.data.createdStore(new addStoreData());
    $scope.userInfo.merge(verifiedEmployee);
    $scope.verifiedEmployee = verifiedEmployee;
    console.log($scope.userInfo.data.refCode());
    };
```

Comment: Why not something like $scope.userInfo= {} ??

Comment: @ManuelObregozo and tried it, but without success

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion everything works as it should.
The `data` property will be set in each object constructed by `new userInfo()`. Because you set this property in `prototype`.

So, here is what your code do:

- 1) You create new instance of `userInfo()` which you save in `user_info`. Now `user_info` has `data` property.
- 2) You delete property `userInfo` of `$scope` object, whatever it was. Now `$scope.userInfo` is `undefined`. But the origin function `userInfo` still exists, because you didn't delete it. Also you actually can't delete it with `delete` keyword, because you created it using `var` keyword (while so it becomes non-configurable). More about [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- 3) You reassign `userInfo` property of `$scope` object to earlier created (and still existed, of course) `user_info`, which is an instance of origin `userInfo` and has `data` property. So now `$scope.userInfo` has data property.

In total, if you want to delete information in `$scope.userInfo` then you did it right: `delete $scope.userInfo`. If you want to delete information in origin `userInfo` function, you can do so for example: `userInfo = null`.

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wuWMvdtwLcARTATaS4dO?p=preview) with your code.

Comment: Adding to pay attention to $scope.apply() function!

Comment: @GProst i make some changes and this is my final code , but the problem is not solved.